# Communicate with applets using another logical channel

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

I build a .cap file using the below code from [here](http://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/) :

```
package helloWorldPackage;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet {
         private static final byte[] helloWorld = {(byte)'H',(byte)'e',(byte)'l',(byte)'l',(byte)'o',(byte)' ',(byte)'W',(byte)'o',(byte)'r',(byte)'l',(byte)'d',};

         private static final byte HW_CLA = (byte)0x80;
         private static final byte HW_INS = (byte)0x00;

         public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
             new HelloWorldApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
         }

         public void process(APDU apdu) {

             if (selectingApplet()) {
             return;
         }

         byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
         byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);
         byte INS = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] & 0xFF);

         if (CLA != HW_CLA)
        {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

          switch ( INS ) {
             case HW_INS:
               getHelloWorld( apdu );
               break;
            default:
               ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
         }
   }

  private void getHelloWorld( APDU apdu)
  {
      byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
      short length = (short) helloWorld.length;

      Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(helloWorld, (short)0, buffer, (short)0, (short) length);

      apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, length);
  }
}
```

The above applet uploaded with `AID = 0102030405060708091111`.And I successfully sent SELECT command And the `8000000B` command,And receive **HelloWorld** in response.

```
OpenSC-Tool> opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708091111 -s 800000000b
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 11 11
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 80 00 00 00 0B
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 Hello World
```

As far as I know, The low nibble in CLA of command indicate the number of channel,right?
so why when I want to communicate with the applet using logical channel number 1, I receive `6E00` for second APDU command :

```
OpenSC-Tool> opensc-tool -s 01a404000b0102030405060708091111 -s 810000000b
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 01 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 11 11
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 81 00 00 00 0B
Received (SW1=0x6E, SW2=0x00)
```

And :

```
OpenSC-Tool> opensc-tool -s 01a404000b0102030405060708091111 -s 800000000b
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 01 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 11 11
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 80 00 00 00 0B
Received (SW1=0x6E, SW2=0x00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first command sequence:

```
<<< 01 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 11 11
>>> 90 00
>>> 81 00 00 00 0B
<<< 6E 00
```

You receive the status word `0x6E00` because that's what your applet code does:

```
byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);

if (CLA != HW_CLA)
{
    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
}
```

So if the class byte of the APDU is not equal to `0x80`, which is the case if you use logical channel 1 (as it is `0x81` in that case), you throw an `ISOException` with error code `0x6E00` (`ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED`).

Regarding the second command sequence:

```
<<< 01 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 11 11
>>> 90 00
>>> 80 00 00 00 0B
<<< 6E 00
```

You select the applet on logical channel 1 and then send the command `80 00 00 00 0B` on the basic channel. As your applet is not selected on the basic channel, there is no recipient that understands commands in the proprietary class. THus, you receive the status word `0x6E00` (`ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED`).

Comment: So That means my applet works correctly only on basic channel.Is this right?

Comment: Excuse me, When I select an Applet on the card by `00 A4 04 ...`, The next commands that I send go directly to the applet? or ISD or another primary applet receive the APDUs first and if they aren't `Select Command`, sends them to the selected applet?

Comment: Yes, the next command on that logicial channel will be passed directly to that applet (unless it's another application selection command).

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "correctly", I would say that your applet works "correctly" on other channels too. You just implemented your applet to behave differently on other that the basic logical channel.